# raise error application

Tags: javascript, jquery, plsql

I need to find substitute solution for my problem with pl sql raise error.

My code:

```
 elsIF :P79_TIP_IZV='ZS' and (:P79_P_VRSTA <> 'IZD' or :P79_VRSTA <> 'MSK' or :P79_P_VRSTA <> 'POI' or :P79_P_VRSTA <> 'ISI' or :P79_P_VRSTA is null)
   then
          raise_application_error (
               -20031,'You have to choose -  MSK, IZD, ISI or POI.');
```

This code is calling a report from button and when it is all true I get this message in new tab in URL link:

```
ORA-20031:%20You %20have %20to %20choose .%20MSK,%20IZD,%20ISI%20ori%20POI.
```

I want a popup to show this message when the button is pressed, before opening the report.

Comment: I don't know about your JS popup logic, but the validation logic looks wrong because there is no possible value of `:p79_p_vrsta` that will avoid the error message. (And is `:p79_vrsta` trhe same thing?) Also _'you have to choose'_ is a weird message. A more conventional wording would be something like _'Valid values for xxx are aaa, bbb and ccc'_.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I corrected that variables, but my question remains about raise error application

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes me think you are using Oracle Application Express. If yes, and this code is written as a page process, you have to write javascript Dynamic Action with this logic and assign it to the button. PL/SQL validation code executes after submit and before page load. The result of PL/SQL process you will see only on next page.